# What are the database options for a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

According to railsguides, when you initiate a rails app, you can choose to use a non-SQLite database.  This is accomplished with the `-database` flag, which " allows you to choose an adapter from a list of the most used relational databases".  For example (in the shell):

> rails new my_app_name —database=mysql

What are the database options and associated syntax for choosing them?  Thanks!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.15/getting_started.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `rails new --help`:

```
-d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: 
mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/
jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
```

So, those are the options.  This is 4.0.2.